# How Do I Destroy Finished Walking Particle (Clones) in UNITY?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/e72af79b83c0b50e12f2998ee12e4806) < in the video I have a walking particles that appear when ever my player moves left and right but I want them to be destroyed after the particles are finished fading away I tried using ***stop action*** in unity but that only destroyes the finish particles when the player stops moving and after that the particles will
stop showing up

these are my dublicated particles that will stay in my game forever and cause lag later on I need a way to stop showing them when they are done
[image]

[IMAGE](https://gyazo.com/03536314559d6fa12609de9412464767) < the inspector of my particles
[image](https://gyazo.com/610144646c34bb4fc1d5abd51c65a31c) < the name of my particles
is there a way I could some how in my code check if the particle is faded away or check if its finished and then destroy those because sometimes with the destroy it will destroy everything and the particles wont show up if I walk again

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class partscript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick2;
    public GameObject hays2;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    // public bool show = true;
    public Animator animator3;
    // public Transform player;
    //public Transform  particleposition; 



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //transform.position = particleposition.position;
        animator3 = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
    }
    //destroy(hays);
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {




        if (joystick2.Horizontal <= -.2f)
        {

            Instantiate(hays2, transform.position, hays2.transform.rotation);



        }

        if (joystick2.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {

            Instantiate(hays2, transform.position, hays2.transform.rotation);




        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, instantiating a game object in update is not the best way to go considering that if your game runs at 60 frames per second you will end up creating 60 game objects each second which can and most likely will affect performance especially on a mobile device which you are working.

But into the point, you can call the Destroy method and pass the duration of the particle.

```
GameObject hay = Instantiate(hays2, transform.position, hays2.transform.rotation);
ParticleSystem p = hay.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
float duration = p.duration + p.startLifetime;
Destroy(hay , duration);
```

If your particle's duration is fixed you can always skip the part where we get the duration via script and simply pass it in the Destroy method.

```
GameObject hay = Instantiate(hays2, transform.position, hays2.transform.rotation);
Destroy(hay , 5f);
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If you like to improve your performance i would recommend to check Coroutines instead of using update.

Comment: what is that ? could you explain

Comment: @JohnP a Coroutine will not bring any gain in this case. In general all coroutines receive their `MoveNext` call right after `Update` (except for special cases like `WaitForEndOfFrame`) so they are called just as often as `Update` ;)

Comment: @HabibIsmail look into [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling) ! As mentioned in this answer using `Instantiate` and destroying objects each frame is extremely expensive! Object pooling allows to instead if destroy objects only deactivate them and reuse them later like it was a new instance which is way less performance intense

Comment: @derHugo Since OP looks to be a beginner in Unity, i was thinking a simpler solution of calling an Ienumerator and instantiate a game object maybe every 0.5 of a second or something similar. Sloppy but better than spawning objects in update. However object pooling is defiantly the way to go.